# Check whether website is able to load or not in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am loading website in `WebView`. Sometimes, When User does not have internet connection in device and if user tries to load WebView, then It shows error in loading website. By which, user comes to know about website url.


How to prevent this problem ?

Comment: Check internet connection while you want to load website in webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check by this :

```
 public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext() 
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {

        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                    return true;
                }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Now call it by:

```
   if(isConnectingToInternet()) {

     // Load your website in webview

   } else {
          // No Internet connection

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from seeing the error page you could override the [onReceivedError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) callback:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError (WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
       final String myErrorPageUrl = "...";
       view.loadUrl(myErrorPageUrl);
    }
}
```

Take care to still provide useful information to the user. Ideally your custom error page would still contain the error description.

The benefit of the above solution is that it will work even if the connection times out or fails for any other reason (like your server being down).